# Spring boot 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot to create a web service where I have a list of shops with their costumers and their cards. Very easy *maybe*.

I use hibernate 4 to connect to the local MySQL database.

The issue is that I get this error (already mentioned in the question):

```
2017-03-17 17:46:45.024 ERROR 2055 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cardController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cardService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cardServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cardDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cardDao' defined in file [/Users/mitro/Documents/SpringBoot/FidelityCard/target/classes/net/mitro/dao/CardDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at net.mitro.FidelitycardApplication.main(FidelitycardApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cardServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cardDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cardDao' defined in file [/Users/mitro/Documents/SpringBoot/FidelityCard/target/classes/net/mitro/dao/CardDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cardDao' defined in file [/Users/mitro/Documents/SpringBoot/FidelityCard/target/classes/net/mitro/dao/CardDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(HibernateDaoSupport.java:117) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

The code is divided in packages that are: controller, dao, model and service. Classes are very similar so I will just post one of them.

**CardController**:

```
package net.mitro.controller;

import net.mitro.service.interfaces.CardService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mitro on 15/03/2017.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cards")
public class CardController {

    @Autowired
    private CardService cardService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List getAllShops(){
        return cardService.getAllCards();
    }
}
```

**CardServiceImpl**:

```
package net.mitro.service;

import net.mitro.dao.interfaces.CardDao;
import net.mitro.service.interfaces.CardService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mitro on 15/03/2017.
 */
@Service
public class CardServiceImpl implements CardService{

    @Autowired
    private CardDao cardDao;

    @Override
    public List getAllCards(){
        return this.cardDao.getAllCards();
    }
}
```

**CardDaoImpl**:

```
package net.mitro.dao;

import net.mitro.dao.interfaces.CardDao;
import net.mitro.model.Card;
import org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mitro on 15/03/2017.
 */
@Repository("cardDao")
public class CardDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements CardDao{

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List getAllCards() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().find("from card");
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public int cardCount() {
        return DataAccessUtils.intResult(getHibernateTemplate().find("select count(*) from card"));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(this.findById(id));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Card findById(int id) {
        return (Card) getHibernateTemplate().get(Card.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insert(Card card) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(card);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Card card) {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(card);
    }
}
```

**Card**:

```
package net.mitro.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by mitro on 15/03/2017.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "card")
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_card")
    private int idCard;
    @Column(name = "stamps_num_card")
    private int stampsNumCard;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop")
    private Shop shop;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    private User user;

    public Card(){}

    public void setStampsNumCard(int stampsNumCard) {
        this.stampsNumCard = ++stampsNumCard;
    }

    public int getIdCard() {
        return idCard;
    }

    public int getStampsNumCard() {
        return stampsNumCard;
    }

    public void setShop(Shop shop) {
        this.shop = shop;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Shop getShop() {
        return shop;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

I really don't understand what I'm missing also my pom looks fine to me, since I added Spring boot JPA 
**pom.xml**

```
...
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

SO how should I instantiate this sessionFactory or hibernateTemplate? I tried to autowire them, but it's not possible.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use the standard JPA API rather than the old, proprietry Hibernate API. And while you're at it, use spring-data-jpa, which integrates easily into spring-boot, and will generate your DAOs for you.

Comment: So is it better to use JPA over Hibernate?

Comment: JPA is just a specification, defining a standard API. Hibernate is one of the implementations of this specification. You can use Hibernate, but you should use it through the standard JPA API rather than through the old proprietary Hibernate API. Just like you don't use the internal Tomcat API to develop a webapp. You use the standard servlet API.

Comment: could you suggest an how to? I just started with Spring and I'm trying to understand many things

Comment: is this https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ the new way?

Comment: If by "new" you mean "less than a few years old", then yes :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Spring Data JPA (as your `pom.xml` would suggest) there's no sense in using obsolete `HibernateTemplate`.

Spring Boot doesn't create `SessionFactory` bean when Spring Data JPA is in use, however it creates `EntityManagerFactory`.
You may autowire it and unwrap to `SessionFactory`.

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {  
   return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

Also you may bind `Session` to `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext`.

However Spring Data JPA repositories are using different context.

I wasn't able to create a Spring project in which `HibernateTemplate` and Spring Data JPA repositories share `Session` context.